# sails js - create seo friendly url

Tags: seo, sails.js

I have created sails js appication. Now I want to create seo friendly url for my application. Is there any plugins for sails js to create seo friendly url or should I create them manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sails.js, you can set up your routes to something like (assuming you're setting up a blog app)

`'get /articles/:title': {
    controller: ArticlesController
  }`

And inside `ArticlesController`, you can have a function that creates url slugs from the blog post title (something like [SpeakingURL](http://pid.github.io/speakingurl/)). You then save this in your `models/Articles.js` in a post-title field. Now, everytime someone wants to visit `example.com/articles/how-to-get-cats-to-like-you`, it will automatically fetch the relevant article.